# copy_to/from_user and malloc in user space

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm in confusion!

I have a simple chardev and user space app that sends/receives a buffer to/from chardev via `ioctl`.

When I allocate the buffer (in user space) via `malloc` (on heap) I sometimes have a segmentation fault in user space app on `free()` or kernel panic.
And every time something one of them.

**But**, If I replace `malloc()` by`alloca()` (allocate buf on stack) everything works fine every time.

Also I tried `memset(buf, 0x42, buf_len)` after calling `malloc`(to avoid compiler optimization or lazy allocation / copy on write)
and it doesn't help.

Could you please explain such behavior?
What is the problem with `malloc` / what am I doing wrong?

Comment: would really need to see the code to identify the problem.

Comment: Could be a buffer overflow and undefined behaviour.

Comment: Two more wild guesses: your driver tries to access the buffer after it's freed by userspace (shouldn't cause kernel panic if you use proper functions, though); your driver tries to write to userspace when it's in another process' context.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I can't post code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @VadimStupakov *I can't post code.* Then how much help can you expect to get?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, So why everything is ok with buffer on stack(alloca)?

Comment: @VadimStupakov I don't know, undefined behaviour ? Why are you not able to post code ?(!)

Comment: without the code, we can only guess as to what the mistake in your code is. debugging the code is your only hope - try running it with something like valgrind and seeing what errors that throws up?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Because there is big amount of code. I try to reproduce such behavior in samples and then post the code.

Comment: @VadimStupakov Assuming you have a memory-management issue in your user-space code, you will probably find the problems a lot faster using a tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/about.html) than you will by changing things hoping to find what's wrong.

Comment: I don't ask you to debug my code. I ask to explain such behavior, If such usage of copy_to/from_user and malloc could lead to error. Or maybe there could be some buf preparation on heap before sending it to kernel space.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, thanks. I try to use Valgrind.

Comment: @VadimStupakov The errors you're seeing are [classic user-space memory corruption symptoms.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption)

Comment: I agree with @AndrewHenle; this smells like a user-space memory management issue. If valgrind isn't an option, you could try writing `my_malloc` and `my_free`, log the requests, and make sure you don't have a use-after-free based on the location of the segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions!
The problem was in the user space side (classic user-space memory corruption symptoms).
So, it is safe to use malloced buffers in kernel space <-> user space communication.

I just thought that there is some special rules to put buffer on heap into the kernel space.